# Change date format which include text using datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas df with a column of dates where the dates are written as "Monday, March 19, 2001 at 3:30:00pm GMT", "Wednesday, April 11, 2001 at 9:00:00pm GMT", "Tuesday, April 3, 2001 at 2:00:00pm GMT", and so forth.

I wish to convert it to "19/03/2001", 11/04/2001, 03/04/2001, and so fourth. Is there a way of doing this using datetime?

Comment: did you try `pd.to_datetime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

If you have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':["Monday, March 19, 2001 at 3:30:00pm GMT",
                            "Wednesday, April 11, 2001 at 9:00:00pm GMT",
                            "Tuesday, April 3, 2001 at 2:00:00pm GMT"]})
```

Then can do:

```
import calendar
monthdict={v: k for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)}
```

This will create `monthdict`, which will be:

```
{'': 0,
 'Apr': 4,
 'Aug': 8,
 'Dec': 12,
 'Feb': 2,
 'Jan': 1,
 'Jul': 7,
 'Jun': 6,
 'Mar': 3,
 'May': 5,
 'Nov': 11,
 'Oct': 10,
 'Sep': 9}
```

Then extract the month data from the strings in your df:

```
months=[monthdict[each] for each in df['Dates'].str.split(',').str[1].str.split(' ').str[1].str[:3]]
```

Extract the days:

```
days=df['Dates'].str.split(',').str[1].str.split(' ').str[2]
```

Years:

```
years=df['Dates'].str.split(',').str[2].str.split(' ').str[1]
```

Put it back together to a list of `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
dts=[datetime.datetime(int(year), (month), int(day)) for year, month, day in zip(years,  months, days)]
```

Transform it to a df:

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'NewDates':dts})
```

If want to convert these `datetime.datetime` objects to strings in some another format, can do:

```
newdf['FormattedDates']=newdf['NewDates'].apply(lambda row: repr(row.day)+'/'+repr(row.month)+'/'+repr(row.year))
```

You will end up with:

```
    NewDates    FormattedDates
0   2001-03-19  19/3/2001
1   2001-04-11  11/4/2001
2   2001-04-03  3/4/2001
```

(I recommend using `datetime.datetime`s rather than strings though.)

Comment: Might very well be easier ways than this.

Comment: yep, you can use the `pd.to_datetime` method and specify the format and use `.dt.strftime` on top of the pandas datetime object to create cosmetic date. using this much iteration in pandas is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
def str_to_datetime(s):
    return datetime.strptime(" ".join(s.split()[1:4]), "%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives "'Series' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality.